# Container Initiation Failed - Deploying Artifactory Using Helm Charts in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I tried installing jfrog artifactory using Helm charts.
`artifactory-0` pod is waiting indefinitely for container initialization.

I used this link https://hub.helm.sh/charts/jfrog/artifactory-oss to install Jfrog Artifactory.

I'm using kubernetes v1.14. On Premise VM, ESXI Hypervisor.

---

**EDIT 02/Mar**

PV:

```
volume-artifactory-0                       10Gi       RWO            Retain           Bound    default/artifactory-volume-artifactory-oss-artifactory-0                                  7m
volume-postgresql-0                        10Gi       RWO            Retain           Bound    default/data-artifactory-oss-postgresql-0                                                 5m38s
```

PVC:

```
artifactory-volume-artifactory-oss-artifactory-0   Bound    volume-artifactory-0                       10Gi       RWO                                  9m19s
data-artifactory-oss-postgresql-0                  Bound    volume-postgresql-0                        10Gi       RWO                                  9m3s
```

---

**EDIT 04/mar**

StorageClass:

```
NAME                  PROVISIONER                    AGE
managed-nfs-storage   fuseim.pri/ifs                 132d
standard              kubernetes.io/no-provisioner   156d
```

---

**EDIT 06/mar**

PVC (06/mar):

```
NAME                                               STATUS    VOLUME                                     CAPACITY   ACCESS MODES   STORAGECLASS          AGE
artifactory-volume-artifactory-oss-artifactory-0   Pending                                                                        standard              24s
data-artifactory-oss-postgresql-0                  Pending                                                                        standard              6s
```

---

**EDIT 09/03**

PVC:

```
artifactory-volume-artifactory-oss-artifactory-0   Bound    pvc-3804670b-3e13-4162-bbf9-bb945c45ddbd   10Gi       RWO            managed-nfs-storage   16m
data-artifactory-oss-postgresql-0                  Bound    pvc-18a744d3-3f3d-4a36-b8bc-7ecc593fc04d   10Gi       RWO            managed-nfs-storage   16m
s
```

kubectl get events --sort-by='.lastTimestamp':

```
2m7s        Normal    Created                 pod/artifactory-oss-artifactory-0                                                 Created container wait-for-db
2m7s        Normal    Started                 pod/artifactory-oss-artifactory-0                                                 Started container wait-for-db
100s        Normal    Started                 pod/artifactory-oss-postgresql-0                                                  Started container init-chmod-data
100s        Normal    Created                 pod/artifactory-oss-postgresql-0                                                  Created container init-chmod-data
100s        Normal    Pulled                  pod/artifactory-oss-postgresql-0                                                  Successfully pulled image "docker.io/bitnami/minideb:stretch"
72s         Warning   BackOff                 pod/artifactory-oss-postgresql-0                                                  Back-off restarting failed container
62s         Warning   VolumeFailedDelete      persistentvolume/pvc-97666796-67b0-4152-b801-2cd84dcbc106                         remove /persistentvolumes/default-artifactory-volume-artifactory-oss-artifactory-0-pvc-97666796-67b0-4152-b801-2cd84dcbc106/bootstrap/access/etc/security/join.key: permission denied
58s         Normal    Pulling                 pod/artifactory-oss-postgresql-0                                                  Pulling image "docker.io/bitnami/minideb:stretch"
54s         Warning   Unhealthy               pod/artifactory-oss-artifactory-nginx-54b677c764-2lpws                            Readiness probe failed: Get http://192.168.233.227:80/router/api/v1/system/health: net/http: request canceled (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)
51s         Warning   Unhealthy               pod/artifactory-oss-artifactory-nginx-54b677c764-2lpws                            Liveness probe failed: Get http://192.168.233.227:80/router/api/v1/system/health: net/http: request canceled (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)
42s         Warning   VolumeFailedDelete      persistentvolume/pvc-f2b1461f-35b5-4199-9395-6b0b4ff7ea05                         remove /persistentvolumes/default-artifactory-volume-artifactory-oss-artifactory-0-pvc-f2b1461f-35b5-4199-9395-6b0b4ff7ea05/bootstrap/access/etc/security/join.key: permission denied
```

kubectl get pods:

```
NAME                                                 READY   STATUS                  RESTARTS   AGE
artifactory-oss-artifactory-0                        0/1     Init:3/5                0          12m
artifactory-oss-artifactory-nginx-54b677c764-2lpws   0/1     Running                 6          12m
artifactory-oss-postgresql-0                         0/1     Init:CrashLoopBackOff   7          12m
```

Comment: what are you getting in the events? `kubectl get events --sort-by='.lastTimestamp'`

Comment: 12s         Normal    FailedBinding       persistentvolumeclaim/data-artifactory-postgresql-0                  no persistent volumes available for this claim and no storage class is set

Comment: but, i specified PV and PVC for this pods to use

Comment: could you give more details on where your k8s is running

Comment: My k8s is running on premise VM. hypervisor is Esxi

Comment: This is my current status of artifactory pods: artifactory-oss-artifactory-0                        0/1     Init:CrashLoopBackOff   13         49m
artifactory-oss-artifactory-nginx-8589548fcd-jwq7w   0/1     CrashLoopBackOff        13         49m
artifactory-oss-postgresql-0                         1/1     Running                 0          49m

Comment: check the logs `kubectl get logs POD_NAME`

Comment: artifactory-oss-artifactory-0 pod logs saying Error from server (BadRequest): container "artifactory" in pod "artifactory-oss-artifactory-0" is waiting to start: PodInitializing, but artifactory-oss-postgresql-0 pod logs showing postgressql is setup successful and database system is ready to accept connections.

Comment: Hello, I edited your question with all these information you passed here in the comments, I know you are new, but in the future try too follow this layout.

Comment: I believe it's related to PVC and PV. I tried deploying here and got the same issue. Can you please paste the output of `kubectl get pv` and `kubectl get pvc`?

Comment: i added my PV ans PVC details please check. thank you.

Comment: @SridharP I managed to reproduce the problem and found a solution, can you post `kubectl get sc` because if it's empty then I have an answer for you...

Comment: i added 'kubectl get sc' result, please check

Comment: @SridharP did you had time to check my answer? Does it help with  your case?

Answer (score 0):

> "FailedBinding: no persistent volumes available for this claim and no storage class is set".

- You can learn more about on this [Github Issue](https://github.com/jfrog/charts/issues/612).

I see you have two `StorageClass` configured but **none is set as default.**

- Add this annotation on the `StorageClass` you want to become the **default** on which the artifactory-oss to be deployed (replacing `<your-class-name>` with your SC.

```
kubectl patch storageclass <your-class-name> -p '{"metadata": {"annotations":{"storageclass.kubernetes.io/is-default-class":"true"}}}'
```

Learn more on [Change the default StorageClass Page](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/change-default-storage-class/#changing-the-default-storageclass).

Also I strongly suggest to:

- Check if those `StorageClass` are correctly configured.

  - You can check if your `standard` is correct following the [StorageClasses Docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/storage-classes/#local)
  - The [NFS-Client-Provisioner Tutorial](https://github.com/kubernetes-incubator/external-storage/tree/master/nfs-client) will help you verify the second one.

---

**EDIT:**
After my suggestion above, we started to see different problems in your environment, so in order to help you I'll give you a few troubleshooting pages so you can test the components of your environment:

In your logs I see you are trying to set the NFS Storage, so I recommend:

- First, try setting the local storage as `default` and deploying there, if everything works, you will know the problem is on your NFS settings.
- [How to do NFS with Kubernetes](https://raymondc.net/2018/12/07/kubernetes-hosted-nfs-client.html#1-setting-up-an-nfs-server-inside-the-cluster): follow this procedures to set up deploy a simpler helm chard, so you can be sure your NFS is correctly configured. Learn more here: [Storage Classes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/storage-classes/#provisioner)
- [Jfrog Helm Chart Github Page](https://github.com/jfrog/charts/tree/master/stable/artifactory#nfs): here you can find the instructions about the application you are trying to deploy.
- [Consult the official Installation and Configurations Page](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Installing+Artifactory#InstallingArtifactory-HelmInstallation) and check the --set parameters that would help you.
- [You can start a New Issue](https://github.com/jfrog/charts/issues) if after troubleshooting the installation you believe it's a bug, and get support directly from the developer community.

Comment: i added my pvc details after making one of my storage class default, please check it. any volume is attached to pvc with default storage class

Comment: @SridharP And after setting as default you completely removed the broken installation and tried again? if so and still have problems, please update the logs, events and status to understand where your error is.

Comment: uninstalled previous artifactory and installed again but pods are not coming up. please check i added pvc, status and events.

Comment: @SridharP Since you are using NFS as storage, can you try passing these arguments during your deployment? `--set artifactory.persistence.type=nfs --set artifactory.persistence.nfs.ip=${NFS_IP}` (and set NFS_IP as an environment variable with your NFS IP. Ref: https://github.com/jfrog/charts/tree/master/stable/artifactory#nfs

Comment: @SridharP I also updated my answer with more troubleshooting steps. If my answer was useful, click the upvote button (▲) to the left of it. That way others know that you've been helped. Also see [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)"